# Another regex: square brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have something like: `word[val1|val2|val3]` . Need a regex to capture both: **word** and **val1|val2|val3**

Another sample: `leader[77]` 
Result: Need a regex to capture both: **leader** and **77**

This is what I have so far: `^(.*\[)(.*)` and it gives me: array[0]=word[val1|val2|val3];

array[1]=word[

array[2]=val1|val2|val3]

---

array[1] is needed but without **[**

array[2] is needed but without **]**

Any ideas? - Thank you

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: `<?php $data = explode('[',$input_string); foreach ($data as $dat){echo trim(']',$dat);}`

Comment: Try [`'~(\w+)\[([^][]*)]~'`](https://regex101.com/r/mE7sT8/1). Or [`'~([^][]+)\[([^][]*)]~'`](https://regex101.com/r/mE7sT8/2). See https://ideone.com/O3E1aX

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Perfect! I would accept this as an answer if you post it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
([^][]+)\[([^][]*)]
```

Here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mE7sT8/2)

**Explanation**:

- `([^][]+)` - Group 1 matching one or more chars other than `]` and `[`
- `\[` - a literal `[`
- `([^][]*)` - Group 2 capturing 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a literal `]`.

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/O3E1aX):

```
$re = '~([^][]+)\[([^][]*)]~'; 
$str = "word[val1|val2|val3]"; 
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1]. "\n" . $matches[2];
```

Comment: Note that you do not have to overescape the pattern if you place the `]` and `[` inside the character class as `[][]` (or the negated character class like `[^][]`). Besides, the `]`  char outside a character class does not have to be escaped ever. A pattern with little escapes looks cleaner, but that is just IMHO :)

Comment: And another point: the first `[^][]+` might be replaced with `\w+` if the 1st group should consist of word chars only. Then, the pattern will look like `$re = '~(\w+)\[([^][]*)]~';`. I'd insist on the `+` quantifier as it matches *one or more occurrences* while Jay suggests `*` (zero or more occurrences).

Answer (score 3):

For the either one you can use `\w*(\[.*\])`

`\w*` match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
Quantifier: `*` Between zero and unlimited times

`\[` matches the character `[` literally
`.*` matches any character (except newline)
`\]` matches the character `]` literally

**EDIT**: I kept hammering away to get rid of the brackets and came up with `(\w*)\[([^][]*)]`

**EDIT**: Which I now see Wiktor suggested in comments before I got back with mine.

Comment: It is close but still not what I need. Here is the result of your regex: 0=>from_date_type[1]; 1=>[1] ... Thanks

Comment: @virrion  check my comment and test it with both your cases. but i think this answer will work fine with your given input

Comment: I got this: (.*?)(\[(.*?)\]) 

Result: `0=>from_date_type[1|2|3]; 1=>from_date_type; 2=>[1|2|3]; 3=>1|2|3`. I can use result 1 and result 3 ... Is it possible to shorten it out? Thanks

So I got 2 extra results but it is closest I got so far.